# How to avoid printing -0.00 in c++ when using iomanip

Tags: c++, iomanip

I'm using C++ `iomanip` to output `double` precision numbers in 2 decimal places. But I don't like getting results like `-0.00` as produced in the following code:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <iomanip>
  using namespace std;

  int main(){
    double x=-0.001;
    cout<<setiosflags(ios_base::fixed);
    cout<<setprecision(2)<<x<<endl;
    return 0;
  }
```

The results for other values of `x` are all correctly rounded to 2 decimal places except when `-0.005<x<0`, in which case the annoying `-0.00` is printed instead of `0.00`. The `-0.00` result remains even if one does `x=round(x*100)*0.01` before the `cout` lines using `round` in `cmath`. What manipulators can handle this correctly?

Comment: Thanks, guys! I now understand `round(x*100)` returns `-0` of type `double`. One can do `if(x==0) x=0` after rounding or `if(abs(x)<0.005) x=0` before rounding, but there's no built-in manipulator yet that does this for us.